# approximation of square wave using sinusoidal form

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

let us consider following form
    [image]

it is taken from wikipedia source,i have tried to implement in matlab

```
function x_square=square_wave(f);
%f-given frequency
% let time interval be too big
x_square=0;
t=0:0.001:10;
 k=1:length(t);
 x_square=(sin(2*pi*f*t)+sum(sin(2*pi*(2*k-1)*f*t)./(2*k-1)))*4/pi;
end
```

at first  time it seems to exactly do  as it is given in formula,but it gives me error

```
>> f=1;
>> y=square_wave(f);
Error using  * 
Inner matrix dimensions must agree.

Error in square_wave (line 7)
 x_square=(sin(2*pi*f*t)+sum(sin(2*pi*(2*k-1)*f*t)./(2*k-1)))*4/pi;
```

what it is supposed to be error ?i may need .* multiplication,but any way  is it correct form? thanks in advance

EDITED :

i have  change my code to  this

```
function x_square=square_wave(f);
%f-given frequency
% let time interval be too big
x_square=0;
t=0:0.001:10;
 k=1:length(t);
 x_square=(sin(2*pi*f*t)+sum(sin(2*pi*(2*k-1)*f.*t)./(2*k-1)))*4/pi;
end
```

and get picture

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, your problem reduces to ignoring the fundamental rules of matrix multiplication (e.g.: A:1xM * B:Mx1 = C:1x1, i.e. a scalar, versus B:Mx1 * A:1xN = C:MxN, i.e. a full matrix with the dimensions MxN, versus A:1xM elementwise multiplied with B:1xM is C:1xM).

Your resulting picture is composed of a sinusoid function (coming from the 1st `sin()`-term) and a constant offset which is the result of `sum()` of a vector. You use the elementwise multiplication `.*` but should use matrix multiplication instead:

```
sum(sin(2*pi*(2*k'-1)*f*t)./((2*k'-1)*ones(1,length(t))))
```

So, the correct program is:

```
x_square=0;
t=0:0.001:10;
k=1:length(t);
x_square=sum(sin(2*pi*(2*k'-1)*f*t)./((2*k'-1)*ones(1,length(t))))*4/pi
```

where the key is that `k'` transposes the vector `k` from 1xM to Mx1.

A minor 2nd mistake is that the first `sin()`-term is already included in the formular as (2*k-1) is 1 for k=1, so the 1st sinusoid component would be added twice when writing it down twice.